# Controlling tick labels alignment in pandas Boxplot within subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For a single boxplot, the tick labels alignment can be controlled like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
%matplotlib inline

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.boxplot(column='col1',by='col2',rot=45,ax=ax)
plt.xticks(ha='right')
```

This is necessary because when the tick labels are long, it is impossible to read the plot if the tick labels are centered (the default behavior).

Now on to the case of multiple subplots. (I am sorry I am not posting a complete code example). I build the main figure first:

```
fig,axarr = plt.subplots(ny,nx,sharex=True,sharey=True,figsize=(12,6),squeeze=False)
```

then comes a for loop that iterates over all the subplot axes and calls a function that draws a boxplot in each of the axes objects:

```
    for key,gr in grouped:
        ix = i/ny # Python 2
        iy = i%ny
        add_box_plot(gr,xcol,axarr[iy,ix])
```

where

```
def add_box_plot(gs,xcol,ax):
    gs.boxplot(column=xcol,by=keyCol,rot=45,ax=ax)
```

I have not found a way to get properly aligned tick labels.

If I add 
        `plt.xticks(ha='right')`
after the boxplot command in the function, only the **last** subplot gets the ticks aligned correctly (why?).

Answer (score 3):

> If I add  plt.xticks(ha='right') after the boxplot command in the function, only the last subplot gets the ticks aligned correctly (why?).

This happens because `plt.xticks` refers to the last active axes. When you crate subplots, the one created last is active. You then access the axes opbjects directly<s>(although they are called `gs` or `gr` in your code, whatever that means)</s>. However, this does not change the active axis.

**Solution 1:**

Use [`plt.sca()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.sca) to set the current axis:

```
def add_box_plot(gs, xcol, ax):
    gs.boxplot(column=xcol, by=keyCol, rot=45, ax=ax)
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.xticks(ha='right')
```

**Solution 2:**

Use [`Axes.set_xticklabels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) instead:

```
def add_box_plot(gs, xcol, ax):
    gs.boxplot(column=xcol,by=keyCol,rot=45,ax=ax)
    plt.draw()  # This may be required to update the labels
    labels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.get_xticklabels()]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, ha='right')
```

I'm not sure if the call to `plt.draw()` is always required, but if I leave it out I only get empty labels.

Comment: katzemakase, thanks for your help. Except for the fact that you confuse gs with ax, your Solution 1 does indeed work. Your Solution 2 does NOT work: I get the literal description of the label instead of the actual label. That is, the labels look something like `u\\\'Text(5,0,u...`.

Comment: @germ You are right. I've updated the answer to extract labels from the Text objects in solution 2. Also, I did indeed confuse gs and ax. What is gs?

Comment: yes, your solution 2 now works correctly. `plt.draw()` is not necessary. gs is a pandas groupby object that contains the data to be plotted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `mpl` object oriented interface, you can set the tick parameters for each axis individually.

add a line to set the `xticklabels` within your add_box_plot function (after `gs.boxplot`). Unlike `plt.xticks`, you cannot just give `set_xticklabels` the `ha` keyword, it also requires you to give it a list of tick labels. Here, we can just grab the existing labels with `get_xticklabels`:

```
def add_box_plot(gs,xcol,ax):
    gs.boxplot(column=xcol,by=keyCol,rot=45,ax=ax)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),ha='right')
```

---

Here's a minimal example to show this working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# We'll create two subplots, to test out different alignments
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

# A sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

# Boxplot on first subplot
df.boxplot(ax=ax1)

# Boxplot on second subplot
df.boxplot(ax=ax2)

# Set xticklabels to right alignment
ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(),ha='right')

# Set xticklabels to left alignment
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.get_xticklabels(),ha='left')

plt.show()
```

Notice the `xticklabels` are right-aligned on the top subplot, and left-aligned on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Tom, see comment above about your solution, which is the same as kazemakase's Solution 2. It does not work properly. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: This works for me with a boxplot created from a pandas dataframe. See the example in my edit.